# Read JSON array without curly brackets

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm trying to get the values from array in a JSON file. Array only has a square brackets and not curly brackets something like this: 
"{"name_of_the_array: ["value_1", "value_2"]"}"

I found here some answer but it did not work for me the code of the answer is:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray("array_name");

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

            str = array.get(i).toString();
            list.add(str);
        }
```

the list is ArrayList list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: post your whole json

Answer (score 0):

`{}` denotes a `JSONObject` so you have to create a `JSONObject` first. `[]` denotes a `JSONArray`. You have to fetch the `JSONArray` from  `JSONObject` with `key`.

Use this code

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("array_name");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

        str = array.get(i).toString();
        list.add(str);
    }
```

Check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) and [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) for parsing

Answer (score 0):

```
try something like this
   JSONArray array = new JSONArray("array_name");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

        str = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("string_name");
        list.add(str);
    }

  or you can try this too
  JSONArray array = new JSONArray("array_name");

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

        str = array.getString("string_name");
        list.add(str);
    }
```